# Как добавить свой виджет в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, виджет

Как во фреймворке Yii2 добавить свой виджет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ЧТобы добавить свой виджет, вы должны создать класс, отнаследовав его от **yii\base\Widget** и как минимум определить в нем метод run()

метод run() должен возвращать строку html которая и будет вставлена в месте вызова этого виджета. Можно возвращить как готовую строку html вручную так и результат рендеринга $this->render(). В этом случае фреймворк сначала будет искать нужное представление в папке **view**, находящейся в одной папке с вашим виджетом.

Рекомендуется "складывать " ваши собственные виджеты в под-папку **widgets** приложения или модуля, но вы вольны сами выбирать месторасположение для подобных классов.

У меня, например, некоторые виджеты попадают в папку **components**

Comment: Премного благодарен!